# asp.net listbox on selectindexchanged doesn't fire an event

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:ListBox ID="list1" runat="server" Height="200" Style=" margin: 0"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="list1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
```

i have listbox in the updatePanel

but when i select something it doesn't fire an event what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to Set `AutoPostBack` Property to True.  then only Postback happens and your selected index event will fire.

```
<asp:ListBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="yourLIst" runat="server" Height="200" Style=" margin: 0"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="yourLIst_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to set [`AutoPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx) to `true` (default is `false`):

```
<asp:ListBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="list1" runat="server" Height="200" Style=" margin: 0"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="list1_SelectedIndexChanged">
   ....
```

Also note that you have to databind the ListBox only on the initial load not on every postback, so use the `IsPostBack` property to check it:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if(!IsPostBack)
        DataBindListBox();
}
```